# Connection is still Idle in Channel in Mirth Connect

Tags: mysql, hl7, mirth

I first created channel in Mirth Connect which connection to MySql.At first, it works fine,when I see in Dashboard,I can see my channel with 'Connected' connection.But,somehow, when I restart my computer and reopen the Mirth Connect Administrator,I only find that connection is Idle.How can I make this to 'Connected' Status to test with channel.Please help.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is this an inbound or an outbound channel? When you have an inbound connection from another machine or system, you have to ensure that whatever that other system is keeps the connection open. If this is an outbound connection from Mirth (assuming TCP Sender), there is a setting under Edit Channel --> Destinations --> TCP Sender Settings --> Keep Connection Open. Set that to Yes and it should maintain an open connection with the receiving system.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `Send Timeout` to 0 ms.
This will keep the connection opened indefinitely.